# Save a Value From an HTML Form in a Javascript File Without Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, web-deployment

So as the title describes I would like to essentially grab a value submitted in an HTML form and then save that to a Javascript file without resetting everything on the page. Also in case it's important I am using Django.

I tried to use onsubmit to call a method in the Javascript file that would store the input elements value into a variable and then return false but that did not work.

This is the code baseline I'm working on right now.

```
<form onsubmit="return commandSubmission()">

            
            <input class="play-button-style" type="hidden" id="send" value="Send" disabled="disabled"/>
            
            <input type="hidden" id="command" name="command" disabled="disabled">

</form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function commandSubmission(){

//PREVENT HTML FORM SUBMIT
return false;
```

}

Comment: Your approach is possibly not right - if you don't want to actually submit the form to anywhere, then there's no need to use form submission.  If you want to just grab the values from different fields on the page, you can just use document.getElementById('myField').value, and then put that value where you want.  I will admit I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "save that to a Javascript file" ... you want to save it to a file on the user's machine, or somewhere on a server?

Comment: @Craig Ya essentially what I mean is I want them to press a button and send something they type in an input box to be stored in a variable in a javascript file on the server.

Comment: Well, there are probably a number of different ways this could be approached.  You could use AJAX (XmlHttpRequest object) to submit the value to the server, without requiring a form submission.  Otherwise, you could still do a form submission, but if you want to retain all of the values that have been entered in different fields, then just read the values from the post request (Django has the collection of form fields in HttpRequest.POST), and set those values on the form fields when the page renders again.

Comment: By the way, I must admit that I'm still not sure exactly what your use-case is for dynamically writing values to a javascript file that's saved on a server .... Depending on the final result that you're trying to achieve, there could be a better overall approach